# Bash: how can I loop through a directory's files?

Tags: bash

In Bash, what would a for **_ in _** loop look like if I'm trying to loop through all files in a directory and preform a command on them?

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *
do
    perform_command_on "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple `for`

```
for f in dir/*; do echo "Processing $f file.."; done
```